# merge array object within array based on same id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I have a 2 variable with object and with a value of array object, in "test" and "test_2" i would like to merge the sku ("test") and feature ("test_2) based on id (as per below). What is the best way to merge, Im thinking of, for the test_2 I convert the feature into value array object ex: feature:[{id:xxx}] first and after that I do the merge, as I try it doesn't work. Hope anyone here can help me. Thank you

```
const test = 
    {
        sku: [
            {id:"282828282", link:"ksksks.com"},
            {id:"676867868", link:"lallaa.com"},
            {id:"543454554", link:"sssss.com"},
            {id:"345473663", link:"fdfsas.com"}
        ],
      
    }

const test_2 = 
{
        panels: [
            {id:"9328492847", feature: ['282828282']},
            {id:"6756734535", feature: ['543454554', '282828282']},
            {id:"6545353453", feature: []},
            {id:"4353567688", feature: []},
        ]
}
```

```
const test_3 = 
{

        panels: [
            {id:"9328492847", feature: [{id: '282828282', link:"ksksks.com"} ]},
            {id:"6756734535", feature: [{id: '543454554', link:"sssss.com"}, {id:'282828282',link:"ksksks.com"}]},
            {id:"6545353453", feature: []},
            {id:"4353567688", feature: []},
        ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let skuSet = {};

for (let i = 0; i < test.sku.length; i++) {
    if (!skuSet[test.sku[i].id]) {
        skuSet[test.sku[i].id] = test.sku[i];
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < test_2.panels.length; i++) {
    let current = test_2.panels[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < current.feature.length; j++) {
        if (skuSet[current.feature[j]]){
            current.feature[j] = skuSet[current.feature[j]];
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test_2));
```

Let me know if you have any question regarding above logic.

Comment: hi garry thank you very much, this really solve my question

Answer (score 0):

```
let skuMap = {};

test.sku.map((skuData) => { skuMap[skuData.id] = skuData })
test_2.panels.map((panelData) => {
  panelData.feature = panelData.feature.map((panelFeatureId) => skuMap[panelFeatureId])
})
```

Simple and fast